# Refresh the page on close of popup window

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, telerik

How can I refresh the parent page on close of popup window. The close function is a RadCodeBlock client script. How can I refresh the parent page from the given close function?

```
<telerik:RadCodeBlock runat="server" ID="rcb1">
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function GetRadWindow() {
            var oWindow = null;
            if (window.radWindow)
                oWindow = window.radWindow;
            else if (window.frameElement.radWindow)
                oWindow = window.frameElement.radWindow;
            return oWindow;
        }

        function Close() {
            var result = window.confirm("Are you sure you want to close the window!");
            if (result == true) {
                var oWindow = GetRadWindow();
                oWindow.argument = null;
                oWindow.close();
                return false;
            } 
        }
    </script>
</telerik:RadCodeBlock>
```

Comment: Perhaps first consider why you need to reload the page. Perhaps the popup can ajax in the new data? Otherwise it is normally done with an `opener.reload(1)` (for popups) and `top.reload(1)` (for frames) Additionally you can do `if (window.confirm("Are you sure you want to close the window!")) { ...`

Comment: I need to reload the parent page because I am updating the tables from the popup window and the changes should be  reflected immediately in parent page.

Comment: That sounds like a very good reason to use AJAX and a simple div

Comment: How can I do that? Is there any sample code?

Comment: I am opening popup window from ServerSide like the following `ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page, Page.GetType(), "someKey", script, true);` And the `opener.reload(1)` does not work.

Comment: But why `opener.reload(1)` is not working.

Comment: I cannot tell. I have no idea what `ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page, Page.GetType(), "someKey", script, true);` translates to in JS. If there is a window.open in there, opener could work

Comment: @gofr1 Could you please look into this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a working example from one of my old projects. Perhaps it may give you some ideas.

**ASPX**

```
<telerik:RadWindowManager ID="rwm" runat="server" VisibleStatusbar="false" ReloadOnShow="true">
   <Windows>
       <telerik:RadWindow ID="rw1" Title="My Window" runat="server" Behaviors="Default" OnClientClose="onClientClose">
       </telerik:RadWindow>
   </Windows>
</telerik:RadWindowManager>
```

**JS**

```
function OnClientClose(oWnd) {
     // alert("hello there");
     // you could use the client-side code to rebind the radgrid
     // e.g. 
     // var mt = $find("<%= RadGrid1.ClientID %>").get_masterTableView();
     // mt.rebind();
     // or you can just reload the page
     document.location.reload();
}
```

Alternatively, if you want to rebind or do some other things in the code behind, what you can do is to add a hidden button server control on the page, and then initiate the click event via your JS.

Hope this helps.